# Walk one hour daily during evening

Tags: walking

I am planning to start walking from my work place to my home. It will take 1 hour and 15 minutes(about 6 KM) to reach at my home.

Is there anything strange ? Is it okay for a man aged 28 ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but if you're asking is that a "normal" pace for a 28 y/o man, that is unanswerable. Everyone walks at different speeds.

Comment: JohnP,  My query is perfectly answered by Dark Hippo. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I walk to work most days (I'll admit, I do get lazy if it's raining sometimes), my partner walks to work, lots of the people I work with walk to work.

There's nothing strange with walking to work, it's good exercise.

It should be ok for a man aged 28, assuming there is no medical reason why the man shouldn't be walking 12km a day.

I find it's a good time to listen to music or podcasts and get a little extra learning into my day (occasionally I'll read my Kindle, though that's probably not the smartest move)

Comment: Yes. Dark.I was waiting for an answer like this. I will use this time to learn a new language, using podcasts and conversations.